# How to convert sql insert statement into 1 liner and run one by one in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

Hi I am new in python so asking this question. I have insert query in file.
I have to execute them one by one.
Could you please help me how can I do this? They are saved in text file. They aren't in 1 liner. How can we make them in 1 liner or convert them into dataframe?

Example:
insert_statement.txt

```
INSERT INTO imedical_cleansing_rule_metadata
(
  Data_Set_Name,
  Region,
  Layer,
  Table_Name,
  Column_Name,
  Column_Seq,
  EC2_Source_Path,
  EC2_Target_Path,
  Is_Active,
  s3_tgt_path,
  Rule,
  Spectrum_Table_Name,
  Sub_Rule
)
VALUES
(
  'JGVCC',
  'ASPAC',
  'Raw_Layer',
  'DM_GENESYS_CONVERSTION_AGG',
  'queue_name',
  2,
  '/medaff/Scripts/Incoming_Src_Files/',
  '/medaff/eureka/RawLayer/JGVCC/ASPAC/Genesys/DM_GENESYS_CONVERSTION_AGG/',
  'N',
  's3://itx-{}-jg-aspac/jgvcc/Raw_Layer/DM_GENESYS_CONVERSTION_AGG/',
  'rule1;rule3;rule4;rule2;rule6;rule19',
  'lnd_jgvcc_aspac_genesys_call_detail',
  NULL
);


INSERT INTO imedical_cleansing_rule_metadata
(
  Data_Set_Name,
  Region,
  Layer,
  Table_Name,
  Column_Name,
  Column_Seq,
  EC2_Source_Path,
  EC2_Target_Path,
  Is_Active,
  s3_tgt_path,
  Rule,
  Spectrum_Table_Name,
  Sub_Rule
)
VALUES
(
  'JGVCC',
  'ASPAC',
  'Raw_Layer',
  'DM_EUAVCC_CASE_CRM',
  'parent_case_number',
  1,
  '/medaff/Scripts/Incoming_Src_Files/',
  '/medaff/eureka/RawLayer/JGVCC/ASPAC/CRM/DM_EUAVCC_CASE_CRM/',
  'N',
  's3://itx-{}-jg-aspac/jgvcc/Raw_Layer/DM_EUAVCC_CASE_CRM/',
  'rule1;rule3;rule4;rule2;rule6;rule19',
  'lnd_jgvcc_aspac_crm_activity',
  NULL
);
```

Comment: Probably, a regex would help to combine INSERT statements with values or simple file reading to split data.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all queries are separated by one blank line, you could read and store them in a list:

```
with open("insert_statement.txt", "r") as file:
    query_list = file.read().split("\n\n\n")
    query_list = [query.replace('\n', ' ') for query in query_list]

for query in query_list:
    print(query)
    #  execute(query)
```